# Automatically insert "N/A" when not all expected data received

Tags: php, c, sql-server, arduino, esp32

Is it possible that it can automatically insert "N/A" into the database when I don't receive all the expected data points for the column?

**Esp32 Code**

```
void sendDataToServer(String data) {

HTTPClient http;

  String valuekey;
  if (i<= 29) {
    valuekey = "Value1";
    }else if(i>=30 && i<=59) {
    valuekey ="Value2";
    }else if (i>=60 && i<= 139) {
    valuekey ="Value3";
    }

String url = "http://" + String(serverName)+ "/index.php?" + valuekey + "=" + data;
    http.begin(url);

     int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
  
  if (httpResponseCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
    Serial.println("Server response: " + http.getString());
    Serial.println("Data inserted: " + data);
    i++; 
  } else {
    Serial.println("HTTP request failed with error code: " + String(httpResponseCode));
  }

  http.end();  
}
```

How can I achieve this to keep the number of received value and fill the remainder with "N/A" if it doesn't receive all the data? For example, if the 'Value1' column is set to receive 29 data points but only receives 25, I'd like the remaining 4 to be automatically populated with 'N/A'. Is this possible?

Below is my PHP code.

**PHP Code:**

```
$value1Data = array();
$value2Data = array();
$value3Data = array();


if (isset($_GET['Value1'])) {
    $value1 = $_GET['Value1'];
    $value1Data[] = $value1;
}
if (isset($_GET['Value2'])) {
    $value2 = $_GET['Value2'];
    $value2Data[] = $value2;
}
if (isset($_GET['Value3'])) {
    $value3 = $_GET['Value3'];
    $value3Data[] = $value3;
}


foreach ($value1Data as $value1) {
    $sqlValue1 = "INSERT INTO dbo.ESP (Value1) VALUES (?)";
    $paramsValue1 = array($value1);
    $resultValue1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlValue1, $paramsValue1);

    if ($resultValue1 === false) {
        echo "Error inserting Value1 data: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    } else {
        echo "Data inserted: Value1: " . $value1 . "<br>";
    }
}

foreach ($value2Data as $value2) {
    // Update Value2 column
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE TOP(1) dbo.ESP SET Value2 = ? WHERE Value2 IS NULL";
    $updateParams = array($value2);
    $updateResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $updateQuery, $updateParams);

    if ($updateResult === false || $resultValue2 === false) {
        echo "Error updating or inserting Value2 data: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    } else {
        echo "Data inserted and updated: Value2: " . $value2 . "<br>";
    }
}

foreach ($value3Data as $value3) {
    // Update Value3 column
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE TOP(1) dbo.ESP SET Value3 = ? WHERE Value3 IS NULL";
    $updateParams = array($value3);
    $updateResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $updateQuery, $updateParams);

    if ($updateResult === false || $resultValue3 === false) {
        echo "Error updating or inserting Value3 data: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    } else {
        echo "Data inserted and updated: Value3: " . $value3 . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: All those classifications on the sensor side (ESP32) and the database storing side are not necessary, you can send the data as is, and only apply the logic when retrieving the data from the database for application.

Comment: It's not clear what Value1, Value2, Value3 are - do these columns contain serialized data? Note that if there is a mismatch in calling the PHP code, some Value2 or Value3 may be assigned to the wrong record.